# use std::initialiser_list to explicitly initialise a variable

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

this code

```
std::initializer_list<const char*> list {"something", "somthingElse" /*..*/};
const char* array[] = list;
```

fails to compile with the following error on error:

```
array initializer must be an initializer list
```

Can't really understand what I'm doing wrong here since I'm using an `initializer_list` after all.

(The reason I use an `initializer_list` is so I can use `list.size()` later in my code in several parts; it'd be error_prone having to adjust a series of magic constants each time I add/remove something from the list)

Comment: Isn't it obvious? An `initializer_list` is not the same as an *initializer list* :) In order to construct something from an `std::initializer_list`, you need a constructor that takes an `std::initializer_list`. A plain array doesn't have one. Also, there are other options like `std::array`, or a plain array and `std::extent`, that allow you to fetch the number of elements in an array.

Comment: @Praetorian Would be a shame to let such a pun go, but you probably meant _braced_ _initalizer_ for the second case :) Edit: rather [braced-init-list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) in cppreference terms

Comment: @Rostislav Yes, it should say *braced-init-list*, or *brace-enclosed initializer-list* as the standard says where it talks about initializing an array of unknown size, but neither of those make for a funny sentence :)

Comment: Similarly, a `std::array` is not an array, and a `std::string` is not a string, as far as the language is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

To initialize an array, you need a *brace-enclosed initializer list* which is not the same as a `std::initializer_list`.

To get what you're trying to achieve, you could use a `std::array`, but you'll need a helper function to deduce its size parameter:

```
#include <array>

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(Ts)> make_array(Ts... i)
{
    return {i...};
}

int main() {
    auto a = make_array<const char*>( "a", "b", "c", "d" );
    return a.size(); // I get an exit value of 4 here
}
```